# 複数の画面間でデータの受け渡し方法

Tags: swift

今Swiftを使って、アプリを作成しています。
１つのページでユーザーが数字を入力できるようになっていて、ユーザーが入力した数字を別のページに表示させたいです。
Swift初心者なのですが、これらのページを作成する手順（どのようなメソッドを用意、クラスは何個必要かなど）を教えて欲しいです。
ちなみにこれらのページを作るためにサーバーは必要ですか？

Answer (score 1):

メソッドやクラスが何個必要になるかは、答えできません。直接探さないとならないです。僕も何個必要になるかは正確にわかりません。でも一応答えてみます。

どのようになっているアプリか把握が難しいけど、入力を受けるページ、そして入力したのを見せるページ合わせてStoryboard上で二つのページが必要です。
UIViewControllerクラスを相続したViewControllerクラスも二つ必要になると考えます。
サーバはアカウントが必要ではないと必要ないです。どんなアプリかが把握が難しいから”これだ！”というのは難しいと思います。
複数の画面間でデータの受け渡し方法はNSNotificationCenterを使う方法があります。

単純に数字を入力すると、その次のページでその数字を出力するのを望んでしますか？
そうではないとなんですか？詳しく教えてください。